# python regex separate assignment statements end with semicolon

Tags: python, regex

I have a string composed of many assignment statements like below. I want to seperate them apart. So I came up with regex `re.findall(r's\d+\.([^=]+)=([^;]+);', string)`

```
s9.allowUpload=null;s9.analyse=null;s9.description=null;s9.fillblankType=null;s9.gmtCreate=1551272584901;s9.gmtModified=1577668049380;
```

It works like

```
[('allowUpload', 'null'), ('analyse', 'null'), ('description', 'null'), ('fillblankType', 'null'), ('gmtCreate', '1551272584901'), ('gmtModified', '1577668049380')]
```

Everything goes fine until I meet a value which also contains semicolon like `s9.optionsDetail` below.

```
s9.type=-1;s9.optionDtos=s42;s9.optionsDetail="[{\"content\":\"<p><span style=\\\"font-size:16px;font-family: \'Calibri\',sans-serif;\\\"  >j*m+i</span></p>\"}]";
```

Comment: Where did the string come from? You are better off finding a library that knows how to parse such a string that trying to cobble together a regular expression for something that appears not to be a regular language.

Comment: @chepner Thank you for your advice, I'm doing a crawler, and these strings are returned after I request xxx.[dwr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWR_(Java)). I know little about that, so I don't know how to search that kind of library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might do is use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match either from `["` to `"]` or match any char except `;` using `(?:"\[.*?\]"|[^;]+)`

```
s\d+\.([^=]+)=((?:"\[.*?\]"|[^;]+));
```

About the alternation

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `"\[.*?\]"` Match from `["` till first occurrence of `"]`
  - `|` Or
  - `[^;]+` Match 1+ times any char except `;`
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x51Frb/1)

Answer (score 0):

@The fourth bird's answer uses the regularity of `optionsDetail` value, it doesn't rootly solve the semicolon occurence in string. Below is an example:

```
s133.plainTextTitle="\u4E49int a[5][5]; \u540E\uFF0C\u662F_________";
```

```
s133.allowUpload=null;s133.analyse=null;s133.description=null;s133.fillblankType=null;s133.gmtCreate=1551272584908;s133.gmtModified=1577668049389;s133.id=1217514489;s133.judgeDtos=null;s133.judgerules="null";s133.ojCases=null;s133.ojMemLimit=null;s133.ojNeedInput=true;s133.ojSupportedLanguage=null;s133.ojSupportedLanguageList=null;s133.ojTimeLimit=null;s133.ojTryTime=null;s133.optionDtos=s174;s133.options=null;s133.optionsDetail="[{\"id\":7679941034291,\"content\":\"<p><span style=\\\"font-size: 16px; font-family: \'Times New Roman\', serif;\\\"  >a[1][0]</span></p>\",\"answer\":true,\"analyse\":null},{\"id\":17679941034291,\"content\":\"<p><span style=\\\"font-size:16px;font-family: \'Times New Roman\',\'serif\';\\\"  >a[0][1]</span></p>\",\"answer\":false,\"analyse\":null},{\"id\":27679941034291,\"content\":\"<p><span style=\\\"font-size:16px;font-family: \'Times New Roman\',\'serif\';\\\"  >a[1][1]</span></p>\",\"answer\":false,\"analyse\":null},{\"id\":37679941034291,\"content\":\"<p><span style=\\\"font-size:16px;font-family: \'Times New Roman\',\'serif\';\\\"  >a[1][5]&nbsp;</span></p>\",\"answer\":false,\"analyse\":null}]";s133.plainTextTitle="\u5728\u5B9A\u4E49int a[5][5]; \u540E\uFF0C\u6570\u7EC4a\u4E2D\u7684\u7B2C6\u4E2A\u5143\u7D20\u662F_________";s133.position=2;s133.sampleAnswerJson="null";s133.sampleAnswers=null;s133.score=2.00;s133.stdAnswer=null;s133.testId=1220061796;s133.title="<p><span style=\"font-size:16px;font-family:\u5B8B\u4F53;\"  >\u5728\u5B9A\u4E49</span><span style=\"font-size:16px;font-family:\'Times New Roman\',\'serif\';\"  >int a[5][5];&nbsp; </span><span style=\"font-size:16px;font-family:\u5B8B\u4F53;\"  >\u540E\uFF0C\u6570\u7EC4</span><span style=\"font-size:16px;font-family:\'Times New Roman\',\'serif\';\"  >a</span><span style=\"font-size:16px;font-family:\u5B8B\u4F53;\"  >\u4E2D\u7684\u7B2C</span><span style=\"font-size:16px;font-family:\'Times New Roman\',\'serif\';\"  >6</span><span style=\"font-size:16px;font-family:\u5B8B\u4F53;\"  >\u4E2A\u5143\u7D20\u662F</span><span style=\"font-size: 16px;font-family:\'Times New Roman\',\'serif\';\"  >_________</span></p>";s133.titleAttachment="null";s133.titleAttachmentDtos=null;s133.type=1;
```

I came up with the idea to split the string using `s133.` which can be got with regex `(s\d+\.)`. Then I will get a list like

```
['', 'allowUpload=null;', 'analyse=null;']
```

After discarding the first element and the `;` at the end of each element, using `split("=", 1)` to split on the first occurence of `=` works just fine.

This method has an obvious shortcoming, it will get false result when `s133.` appears like `s133.plainTextTitle="s133.plainTextTitle"`. But I think this rarely happends.